# How to use Kind instead of Minikube with Cloud Code?

Tags: minikube, kind, google-cloud-code

For reasons of resources (memory and processor), I cannot install Minikube on my pc. While I need it to use Cloud Code's Cloud Run Emulator. I replaced Minikube with Kind and wanted to know how to configure Cloud Code to use Kind.

Comment: From what I have found in docs, no additional configuration is required for kind. Just make sure that your local kubeconfig file mentiones kind cluster and that's it. If you can use kubectl, you should also be able to use Cloud Code. Let me know if this works as mentioned.

Comment: When I launch Run on Cloud Run Emulator automatically, it triggers minikube despite having modified the local kubeconfig configuration of my cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it looks like Cloud Code doesn't currently support configuring the Cloud Run Emulator to use anything other than minikube.

Updating your kubeconfig with your kind cluster works for running on Kubernetes with Cloud Code, but not for Cloud Run.

Looks like you might be stuck with [running locally using Docker](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/testing/local#running_locally_using_docker_with_access_to_services) if you can't install minikube.